# Erro Request Resource is not avaliable

Tags: java, spring

Tenho esta classe em JAVA

```
package br.com.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sistema")
public class SistemaController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/boasvindas", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView boasVindas(@RequestParam(value = "nome", required = false, defaultValue = "insira um texto") String nome) {

         ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("boasVindas");
         modelAndView.addObject("mensagem", "Olá " + nome);

         return modelAndView;
     }
}
```

**Imagem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mensagem de erro:**

> ADVERTÊNCIA: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/SpringRestExample/sistema/boasvindas] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'dispatcher' jan 11, 2018 10:55:40 AM
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

**codigo dispatcher**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.ednilson.cicero.controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Codigo Web.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>Sistema Spring MVC</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list> 

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrigido:

Estava informando o nome do pacote errado:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.tutorialweb.controller"/>
```

Para:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.controller"/>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]